# removing a parent node dependig upon child node using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

i am looking forwar for an template that removes anode from xml depending upon the value of a chid node,basically i am having an xml like:

```
<EventInfo>
    <AssignmentEvent>
        <CreateDateTime>2015-06-02T00:00:00+02:00</CreateDateTime>
    </AssignmentEvent>
    <EstimateEvent>
        <CreateDateTime>2015-06-02T07:38:28.0000000Z</CreateDateTime>
        <CommitDateTime>2015-06-04T14:29:38.0000000Z</CommitDateTime>
        <UploadDateTime>2015-06-04T14:29:39.7651796Z</UploadDateTime>
    </EstimateEvent>
    <OtherEvent>
        <OtherEventType>CalculatedDateTime</OtherEventType>
        <OtherEventDateTime>2015-06-04T14:29:12.0000000Z</OtherEventDateTime>
    </OtherEvent>
    <OtherEvent>
        <OtherEventType>RateDate</OtherEventType>
        <OtherEventDateTime>2015-06-01T00:00:00.0000000Z</OtherEventDateTime>
    </OtherEvent>
    <OtherEvent>
        <OtherEventType>OriginalCommitDateTime</OtherEventType>
        <OtherEventDateTime>2015-06-02T07:42:16.000Z</OtherEventDateTime>
    </OtherEvent>
</EventInfo>
```

i want an xslt template which removes the other event node along with child nodes in which other event type value is OriginalCommitDateTime.

resultant xml would be like

```
<EventInfo>
    <AssignmentEvent>
        <CreateDateTime>2015-06-02T00:00:00+02:00</CreateDateTime>
    </AssignmentEvent>
    <EstimateEvent>
        <CreateDateTime>2015-06-02T07:38:28.0000000Z</CreateDateTime>
        <CommitDateTime>2015-06-04T14:29:38.0000000Z</CommitDateTime>
        <UploadDateTime>2015-06-04T14:29:39.7651796Z</UploadDateTime>
    </EstimateEvent>
    <OtherEvent>
        <OtherEventType>CalculatedDateTime</OtherEventType>
        <OtherEventDateTime>2015-06-04T14:29:12.0000000Z</OtherEventDateTime>
    </OtherEvent>
    <OtherEvent>
        <OtherEventType>RateDate</OtherEventType>
        <OtherEventDateTime>2015-06-01T00:00:00.0000000Z</OtherEventDateTime>
    </OtherEvent>
</EventInfo>
```

i am new to xslt any help would be highly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want an xslt template which removes the other event node along with
>   child nodes in which other event type value is OriginalCommitDateTime.

The standard method to exclude specific nodes is to start with the *identity transform* template to copy all nodes as the rule, then add an empty template matching the nodes you want to exclude as the exception:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OtherEvent[OtherEventType='OriginalCommitDateTime']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```